# Is Firebase Firestore real-time updates using Cloud functions possible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Going through this [blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c), I could see that my app would be better off using the Firebase cloud functions for Firebase Firestore rather than directly accessing Firestore using client-side SDK.

I can implement the Firestore READ operation using `get()`, WRITE operation using `set()` or `update()` &
DELETE using `delete()` methods. All these one-shot operations are fine.

Is possible to implement `addSnapshotListener` to fetch real-time updates? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it technically is possible to use `addSnapshotListener`, there are not a lot of use-cases where this makes sense.

Cloud Functions are short-lived, a maximum of 9 minutes, so not well suited for scenarios where you need to listen to the database for longer times.

Typically, you'll want to instead define a separate Cloud Function that  responds to the thing you'd otherwise want to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

Realtime listeners are not compatible with the way Cloud Functions works.  Functions can only run for a limited amount of time and are shut down after that timeout expires.  Database listeners are indefinite, and will continue listening until they are removed.  If you add a listener inside a function, the system will still shut it down after the function timeout expires.

It's unclear to me **why** you need a listener in a Cloud Functions, but it's almost certainly not the right thing to do, given the way functions work.